# TFS KanBan, How do you view total work done?

Tags: kanban, tfs

We have recently moved to the TFS KanBan boards and I am loving this organization.  Breaking our stories up into smaller, more manageable tasks has been a huge help.  We currently size in hours, and these sizes are on our parent work items.  As new tasks are discovered during our sprint, we add a new child work item to the parent and size it in the "Remaining Work" field in TFS.  The problem is, once I move this child item to the "Done" column, the Remaining Work field is cleared.  I am looking to see the total "Remaining Work" entered on child works items, compared to the size we entered into our parent work item.  Is there a way to pull this information after the completion of the sprint?

(I am not the project manager on my team, just trying to help us improve our sizing efforts as it has gotten us into trouble in the past)

Answer (score 2):

I do not use TFS, nor do I have access to the tool, but from looking at the help page. It appears you specify a "flat-list query" that queries completed tasks and visualize that with a "stacked bar chart" while perhaps specifying size in the "Values" field.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn407521.aspx